# How to use superclass in static method with given Activity parameter?

Tags: java, android

I `m trying to create static class ActivitySetup that is used to set language, theme, etc. for my activities. I have a problem with setting theme. Now i have following code:

```
     static void configureTheme(Activity activity, int defaultTheme) {
     String theme = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity).getString("theme", "light");
     assert theme != null;

     switch (theme) {
         case "light":
             activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
             break;
         case "dark":
             activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat);
             break;
         default:
             activity.setTheme(defaultTheme);
             break;
     }
 }
```

But it crashes. I know that i should use `super (of activity).setTheme` instead of `activity.setTheme`, but how can i do that? How to pass instance of superclass as parameter to a static method?

Comment: `i should use super (of activity).setTheme instead of activity.setTheme` this is wrong. `But it crashes` with crash details in the logcat

Comment: this question is not duplicate of given above [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

switch between themes dynamically you simply need to call `setTheme` before `super.onCreate`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. That is the answer i found:

```
    static int getThemeRes(Activity activity) throws Resources.NotFoundException {
    String theme = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity).getString("theme", "light");
    assert theme != null;

    switch (theme) {
        case "light":
            return R.style.AppTheme;
        case "dark":
            return R.style.Theme_AppCompat;
        default:
            throw new Resources.NotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Call to this method in all activities:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(ActivitySetup.getThemeRes(this));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(LAYOUT); }
```